# Efficient algorithm to calculate Correlation between two Arrays

Tags: c++, correlation

I'm looking for an algorithm to calculate correlation between two array of doubles.

What are the names of the algorithms and I need c++ source code if it's possible.

And by correlation I mean the similarity of data in the array...

for example:

Array1: 1 2 3 
Array2: 2 3 5

should have a higher similarity measure than these 2 arrays:

Array1: 1 2 3
Array2: 9 8 15

Comment: what do you mean by "correlation"?

Comment: If you google "correlation c++", you get plenty of hits, including complete implementations.

Comment: Correlation means similarity of data being presented.

Comment: This question needs a lot more info before it's viable.  For starters, what do you mean by "correlation between two arrays"?

Comment: Also, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient

Comment: @aix ofcourse we get lots of hits, but as we all know first hits aren't always the best, I wanted to ask here, so the professional programmers can lead me in this matter

Comment: @cHao: I think the question is perfectly viable ("correlation" is a very commonly used and very widely understood concept). My main problem with this question is that it can be answered in 5 seconds with a Google search.

Comment: I do not see the problem, could you please be more specific? Just take the definition (like, from Wikipedia) and implement it?

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to *be* a reference. Just because it's on google doesn't mean it shouldn't be asked here. What questions are here that *can't* be answered elsewhere on the internet? The aim would be that StackOverflow becomes the #1 google hit for "correlation C++"

Comment: What is the similarity metric you want to use?

Comment: @tenfour you mean for the "algo" that requires four loops?

Comment: This question is NOT ambiguous. Just see my answer below.

Comment: Not a real question? You don't deserve to have such power to close questions to don't understand. I'm so disappointed in StackOverFlow!

Comment: This question is ambiguous because you mention both correlation and similarity. You haven't clarified which is it that you want to find.

Comment: If this question is ambiguous then how mr aix (who suggested to close this question which he didn't even understand) suggested me to google it! if it's ambiguous then how google can answer my question! This is power misuse

Comment: @EBAG, you're not helping us answer your question by complaining about AIX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to calculate the [sample Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Mathematical_properties): "The above formula suggests a convenient single-pass algorithm for calculating sample correlations". Write a loop to calculate sum(xi), sum(yi), sum(xi^2), sum(yi^2), and sum(xi*yi). Then insert these sums into the formula.